How to Align Product Filter Section to the Left on Both Brand Pages and Shop Page in WooCommerce?
The issue I am encountering is that the product filter section appears on the right side on the brand pages, while it is correctly displayed on the left side of the main shop page. This inconsistency disrupts the user experience and the visual uniformity of my site. I am looking for a way to align the product filter section to the left on both the brand pages and the shop page in WooCommerce. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
side bar is on right
side bar is on left
I have created submenus under the 'Shop' page in the WordPress menu system using the "Perfect Brands WooCommerce" plugin, which provides a brand taxonomy. Each submenu item redirects to a /brand/{brand-name} page. On these brand pages, I expected the product filter section to appear on the left side, consistent with the layout of my main shop page.menu item

That is theme related issue.
